# Создать объект того же типа, что и переданный

Tags: c#, классы, наследование, объекты, типы

Вопрос вроде довольно глупый и базовый, но найти решение в инете не удалось. 
Проблема в том, что не удаётся создать новый объект того же типа, что и переданный. Привожу донельзя упрощённую схему кода:

```
Player[] players = new Player[] { new P1(), new P2(), ..., new Pn() }; 
Player chosen = players[someInt];

Type t = chosen.GetType();
Player FirstEmpty = new t(); // VS: "'t' является переменная, но используется как тип"

// Классы следующие:
abstract class Player {...}
class P1 : Player {...}
class P2 : Player {...}
...
class Pn : Player {...}
```

Нужно для проведения турнира по домино между несколькими алгоритмами.

UPD: Возможно, это делается так, но выглядит это далеко не как адекватный и правильный способ:

```
(Player) chosen.GetType().GetConstructor(new Type[] {}).Invoke(new Player[] {});
```

UPD2: GetType должен, по идее, вернуть один из P*, а не Player?

Comment: Можно использовать [Activator.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wccyzw83(v=vs.110).aspx). Но работает так же медленно через рефлексию.

Comment: а зачем создавать новый объект, если уже есть _chosen_?

Comment: @Grundy как минимум потому, что за две стороны один объект играть не сможет. По крайней мере, в данном случае.

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае создать экземпляр данного типа может быть и нельзя, ведь этот тип вполне может и не иметь конструктора без параметров, или вовсе оказаться синглтоном.

Поэтому адекватного способа нет, задача в общем случае не имеет смысла.

---

Для вашего случая можно было бы, например, заставить классы имплементировать интерфейс `ICloneable` (раз у вас пустой конструктор, то все экземпляры одинаковы, правильно?), и вызвать просто

```
(Player)((ICloneable)chosen).Clone()
```

---

Если вы моделируете игроков разными типами, возможно, вы что-то делаете не так. Возможно, имеет смысл иметь один тип `Player`, а различия между игроками «скармливать» в виде параметров.

Comment: Кажется, на самом деле ему нужна фабрика

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Мне кажется, нужно в реальности composition вместо inheritance, и стратегию игрока инжектить в конструкторе. Но я не знаю точной семантики объектов ТС, приходится гадать.

Comment: Ну не знаю как composition вместо inheritance поможет склонировать объект, но тут явно видно что клонирование автор пытается использовать вместо порождающего паттерна.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: ТС пишет, что ему нужен не клон, а «чистый» объект того же типа. То есть это просто `new Person() { Strategy = oldPerson.Strategy }`.

Comment: Когда у стратегии есть состояние - простое присваивание уже не срабатывает.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, я скорее думал об иммутабельной стратегии, а состояние пусть будет внутри игрока, например.

Comment: Как вы себе представляете общую схему состояния у разных ботов на турнире?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Хм, и правда, состояние стратегии придётся клонировать или создавать заново всё равно. Можно сделать так, чтобы у чистого игрока было чистое состояние (тогда стратегии придётся создавать это состояние у игрока в конструкторе этого самого игрока, например).

Answer (score 0):

Есть класс **System.Activator** (Сводка: Содержит методы, позволяющие локально или удаленно создавать типы объектов или получать ссылки на существующие удаленные объекты. Этот класс не наследуется.)

Если я правильно понимаю вашу цель, что необходимо создать именно новый экземпляр класса (не клон) это должно подойти:

```
SomeType someObject = new SomeType();
Type type = someObject.GetType();
object newObj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
SomeType someObject2 = newObj as SomeType;
```

Расписал только для примера. Так это лучше записать в 2 строки.

Comment: @AGS17, если нет конструктора без параметров, для этого есть перегрузка метода: 
public static object CreateInstance(Type type, object[] args, object[] activationAttributes);
(Сводка: Создает экземпляр указанного типа, используя конструктор, соответствующий заданным параметрам)